# Using Octokit to get the last commit message from a pull request

Tags: c#, .net, octokit

I am planning on using the Get() method to get the last commit of a pull request. But I am not sure how to get the reference to the commit.

````
Task<Commit> Get(string owner, string name, string reference);```
````

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out nevermind.

```
var pullRequest = await client.PullRequest.Get(owner, repo, pullRequestNumber);
var lastCommit = await client.Repository.Commit.Get(owner, repo, pullRequest.Head.Sha);
var commitMessage = lastCommit.Commit.Message;
```